# Axiom Schema of Restricted Comprehension and Big O notation

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, nonstandard-analysis

In this [blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/06/25/ultrafilters-nonstandard-analysis-and-epsilon-management/) about ultrafilters and nonstandard analysis, it is stated that "if we attempt to formalise this by trying to create the set $A := \{ x \in {\Bbb R}: x = O(1) \}$ of all bounded numbers, and asserting that this set is then closed under addition and multiplication, we are speaking nonsense; the O() notation cannot be used within the axiom schema of specification, and so the above definition of A is meaningless."

Why is this true? I thought that the defintion of $O(g(x))$ was $O(g(x)) := \{ f(x) \in {\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}}: \limsup\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} |\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}| <∞\} $, which requires the axiom  schema of specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothetical notation $\{x\in\mathbb R : x=O(1)\}$ seems to be used in the context of a model created as an ultraproduct. It tries to distinguish $x$ *within the non-standard model* by referring to the growth rate of the function *at the metalevel* that represents $x$.

However, the comprehension axiom demands that the property you select a subset by is definable *speaking only about concepts **within** the non-standard model*. The language this property must be phrased in *does not know* that the "reals" of the model are really functions at the metalevel, so it makes no sense to apply big-O notation to them.

Looking in from the metalevel, we can of course form the collection of "reals-in-the-model" that are represented by bounded functions. (Or can we? There's a quotienting step happening on the way to the ultraproduct model, so some numbers will be represented *both* by some function that are $O(1)$ and some functions that aren't. But we could form a collection of reals-in-the-model that have *at least* one bounded representative). But this collection does not correspond to something the non-standard model considers a "set".

Comment: Note that the example was introduced before non-standard constructions and ultrafilters were introduced, indeed it serves as a motivation for their consideration.

Comment: @LutzL: Then I'm at a loss for what it would even _intuitively_ mean for a number to be $O(1)$.

Comment: As I understand it, he wants to introduce the idea of "boundedness" and say that it can not, in a standard context, be affixed to an isolated number. However, in non-standard contexts one can define something like (standard) finite/bounded or appreciable numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is misidentified in the quoted passage:

> "But if we attempt to formalise this by trying to create the set $A := \{ x \in {\Bbb R}: x = O(1) \}$ of all bounded numbers, and asserting that this set is then closed under addition and multiplication, we are speaking nonsense; the $O(\,)$ notation cannot be used within the axiom schema of specification, and so the above definition of $A$ is meaningless."

The problem is *not* that the $O(\,)$ notation can't be used with the axiom schema of specification; $O(\,)$ is a perfectly well-defined notion, and you can use it, for example, to create a set such as $\{f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}  \mid f(x)=O(x^2)\},$ using the axiom schema of specification.  The problem is that the big $O$ notation applies to functions, not to numbers, so the string of characters $"\!x=O(1)\!"$ (where $x\in\mathbb{R})$ may look at first glance like a formula but doesn't actually mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, usually the notation $x=O(1)$ is connected to some limiting process. Without that process, the set $\{x:x=O(1)\}$ as the set of somehow "bounded" numbers is either non-sensical or just is the full set $\Bbb R$, since trivially $|x|\le C$ with $C=|x|$.

What the article is alluding to is probably the idea that elsewhere is called the "appreciable numbers" $x$ with $\exists^{st}N:|x|<N$. Note that there can be no set of appreciable numbers as subset of $\Bbb R$, as there can be no supremum of it. The same goes for the idea of a set of infinitesimals.